# Can I redirect to a third party auth page from a PWA in iOS 11.3?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app with a manifest that specifies “display”: “standalone” mode. This app has always worked great as a PWA on Android. I had avoided Apple’s apple-mobile-web-app-capable mode because in fullscreen mode, links to my external auth provider would open in a separate browser and wouldnt redirect to my standalone instance, making login possible. Now in iOS 11.3, Safari is reading the web app manifest as well, and putting my app into standalone mode. But the same issue seems to be present where the external auth goes out to Safari and cannot complete for the standalone app. Is there a way to work around this? I no longer have a good way to specify that standalone mode should only be used for Android.

Comment: We do facing the same issue with PWA in iOS 11.3 version, @bhollis, if you find any solution for this, please post it here

Comment: We have reported this as bug in safari iOS 11.3. ref: https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=39553656

Comment: @bhollis Did you figure this one out yet? Been stuck on this for a little while now, works perfectly on Android, but in standalone apple mobile devices the redirect opens in Safari not the PWA... can't figure it out... any ideas?

Comment: @Ram I am not able to view your bug report. Have you heard anything about this?

Answer (score 2):

it IS fixed in iOS 12.2 . i tried it myself

Answer (score 1):

Third part auth redirection are currently not supported for pwa in IOS. This is a known issue and it will be probably fixed in IOS 12.2. See https://appyourself.net/en/blog/pwas-under-ios-12-2/